# User was removed and I get negative points?

Tags: support, votes

I have this in my reputation tab within my account.

[image]

Why have I been penalized for a user being removed? Is this justified? To me, the reputation shouldn't be affected.

Comment: What good is a reputation if there is no one to back it up?

Comment: I know what you mean, but that is beside the point I think. If you do some work for a company, who goes under and therefore doesn't pay you. Of course, points is not finance but, the principal is the same. And it does appear that a lot of people already want this (see the link in the comments in Sathya's answer). May be the answer is tough luck and if so, fine, it just seemed to be unjustified.

Comment: The same happened to me!!  I did not even get a change to delete my answer if the user did not like it.  Now I am down -15 for a user that got deleted and I have no idea what happened on the question.

Comment: Also, form the sites perspective, just because a user is deleted doesn't mean the original question is (or isn't) useful... The point of the site is to find answers, deleting them seems counter-intuitive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user had voted on your posts. Since the user is removed, the votes are revoked & consequently, you lose rep.

Comment: Hi Sathya, I've made a small edit to my post as it wasn't clear. My question was supposed to be about not what is going on, but should it be! Why should *my* rep be spoiled?

Comment: @DaveRook The edit spins your question into another different topic - and I agree with you - your rep shouldn't be held at the whims of person who decided to move on. There's a feature request for this [Don't throw away all votes when a user is deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125740)

Comment: Ah, once again Sathya, thank you for your time and help. I understand now.

Comment: @DaveRook: I agree. I think [this sort of thing](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VMZbc.png) is just ridiculous unless it was a sock puppet that was deleted.