# A removed user and their correlated Q&A Votes

Tags: discussion, reputation, votes

Okay, so I noticed a `-10` a few hours earlier and did some reading up on it and everything makes sense and seems pretty clear with regard to what happened, why it affected my rep, etc.

### What I saw

> [image]
>
> [image]

---

### Question

Do the correlated questions and/or answers on someone's account which were affected by this removed account also get adjusted to reflect the negative vote(s)?

- Is there a reason why the correlated questions and/or answers are not listed in conjunction with this adjustment and notification, or is there an easy way to find which questions and/or answers were affected by the adjustment(s)?

*I think answering the sub-question along with the main question on this one post would be super helpful for anyone that may notice this and not be able to find the requested information elsewhere.*

---

### My research / What I read

- [Why do I have a reputation change on my reputation page that says 'User was removed'?](https://superuser.com/help/user-was-removed)
- [User was removed and I get negative points?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/6932/user-was-removed-and-i-get-negative-points)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, when a user is removed without their votes being retained, the votes are nullified, hence your rep change. (If the votes were to be kept, [the Community user would take ownership of them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156520/295684).) Therefore, removed votes no longer contribute to the post score.

There is no simple way to figure out which posts were affected. Vote removal due to user deletion used to show as a bunch of unupvote/undownvote events, but that led to [some confusion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125989/295684). More importantly, Stack Exchange [is concerned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/310859/2825369) that showing that information could allow people to deduce more about person's voting patterns than is already possible. Even though the user is gone, votes are always supposed to be anonymous.

Comment: Of course, "*votes are always supposed to be anonymous*"....